# Why can't I use an if-else statement inside a scriptlet expression, whereas a ternary operator works fine

Tags: jsp, scriptlet

We know that the scripting variable **state** is true.

Why is this scriptlet expression wrong? How would it be the code into _jspService method after translation?

```
<%=
if(state) {
  "yes";
} else {
  "no";
}
%>
```

And this is correct

```
<%= state ? "yes" : "no" %>
```

because returns a value and it would appear into _jspService as

```
public void _jspService(...){
   out.println("yes");
}
```

Comment: The first one wouldn't translate to anything in the `_jspService` method because it's not valid syntax.  It doesn't compile.

Answer (score 2):

The `if / else` version is syntactically different from the ternary operator.  It doesn't "return" anything.

In order to make something like that work you'd need to do this

```
<%
    if (state) {
        out.print("yes");
    } else {
        out.print("no");
    }
%>
```

If statements need something to *do*.  They can't just have a string as their only statements.  The ternary operator chooses *and returns* the selected value.

Scriptlet blocks with the `<%= %>` syntax have to be a single expression that produces a value to output.  Basically they have to evaluate to something.  Even if the `if` statement were syntactically valid, it still wouldn't return a value.

Comment: I know that is right as scriptlet but the question was. Why is wrong as expression <%= ... %>
Is it because we can use if/else inside them?

Answer (score 0):

Roel de Nijs said:

> The JSP expressions <%= ... %> are placed inside a out.print()
>
> So <%= state ? "yes" : "no" %> is converted into out.println(state ?
>   "yes" : "no");, which compiles without any problem. But with the
>   if-statement the resulting code won't compile. That's also why
>   semicolon in a jsp expression is not allowed.